# Angular 4 : Check if radio button selected in a reactive form

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a reactive form with 4 inputs type radio and 4 inputs type text.
I want to display dynamically inputs text following the radio buttons
selected. For example, if button radio 1 selected, i want to display
its corresponding input text 1.

I encounter 2 problems :

- The first radio button is not selected by default (even with attribute checked) and all the radio buttons can be selected at the same time.
- All the inputs text are displayed, i don't know with a *ngIf how to
  check if the radio button corresponding to the input is selected.

**component.html** :

```
<section class="CreateItem" *ngIf="formGroupItemSelection"> 
<form (ngSubmit)="addItem()" [formGroup]="formGroupItemSelection">
  <input formControlName="refNumber" type="radio" value="refNumber" checked> ref number
  <br>

  <input formControlName="partNumber" type="radio" value="partNumber"> part number
  <br>

  <input formControlName="itemName" type="radio" value="itemName"> item name
  <br>

  <input formControlName="manufacturerName" type="radio" value="manufacturerName">manufacturer name
  <br>

  <div *ngIf="formGroupItemSelection.controls.refNumber.valid">
    <input list="refNumbers" formControlName="refNumberSelected" type="text" name="refNumberSelected">
    <datalist id="refNumbers">
      <option *ngFor="let ref of listOfItems">{{ref.refNumber.input}}</option>
    </datalist>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="formGroupItemSelection.controls.partNumber.valid">
    <input list="partNumbers" formControlName="partNumberSelected" type="text" name="partNumberSelected">
    <datalist id="partNumbers">
      <option *ngFor="let ref of listOfItems">{{ref.partNumber.input}}</option>
    </datalist>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="formGroupItemSelection.controls.itemName.valid">
    <input list="itemsName" formControlName="itemNameSelected" type="text" name="itemNameSelected">
    <datalist id="itemsName">
      <option *ngFor="let ref of listOfItems">{{ref.itemDesignation.input}}</option>
    </datalist>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="formGroupItemSelection.controls.manufacturerName.valid">
    <input list="manufacturersName" formControlName="manufacturerNameSelected" type="text" name="manufacturerNameSelected">
    <datalist id="manufacturersName">
      <option *ngFor="let ref of listOfItems">{{ref.manufacturerName.input}}</option>
    </datalist>
  </div>

  <button type="submit [disabled]="!formGroupItemSelection.valid">Valider</button>


</form>
</section>
```

**component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms'
import { ManagementArbologistiqueService } from '../../management-arbologistique.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { matchValuesRefNumber, matchValuesPartNumber, matchValuesItemName, matchValuesManufacturerName } from '../Validators/validators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-selection',
  templateUrl: './item-selection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-selection.component.css']
})
export class ItemSelectionComponent implements OnInit {
  formGroupItemSelection:FormGroup;
  listOfItems = [];

  constructor(public fb:FormBuilder,private managementArbo: ManagementArbologistiqueService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getListBdd();
  }

  initializeForm() {
    this.formGroupItemSelection = this.fb.group({
      refNumber : '',
      partNumber: '',
      itemName: '',
      manufacturerName: '',
      refNumberSelected:[
        null,
        Validators.compose([Validators.required, matchValuesRefNumber(this.listOfItems)])
      ],
      partNumberSelected:[
        null,
        Validators.compose([Validators.required, matchValuesPartNumber(this.listOfItems)])
      ],
      itemNameSelected: [
        null,
        Validators.compose([Validators.required, matchValuesItemName(this.listOfItems)])
      ],
      manufacturerNameSelected:[
        null,
        Validators.compose([Validators.required, matchValuesManufacturerName(this.listOfItems)])
      ]
    })
  }

  getListBdd() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      let subroute = "getRefNumber";
      this.managementArbo.getProducts(subroute)
        .subscribe(
          res => { 
            this.listOfItems = res; console.log('bdd:' + res);
            this.initializeForm();
         },
          err => console.log(err),
          () => console.log('getProducts done'));
    });
  }

  addItem() {

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

1.-NOT use "checked". just when you create the form give the correct value. And the correct value is not "true"

```
this.formGroupItemSelection = this.fb.group({
      refNumber : ['refNumber'], //NOT is true or false 
      partNumber: [],
      itemName: []
      ....
})
```

2.-When we make a *ngIf into a reactive form use myform.get('mycontrol'), e.g.

```
<div *ngIf="formGroupItemSelection.get('partNumber').valid">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem !

Firstly, I found important information in the angular doc to answer my first question :

"*To use radio buttons in a template-driven form, you'll want to ensure that radio buttons in the same group have the same name attribute. Radio buttons with different name attributes do not affect each other.*".

Then, in the case of a reactive form :

"*When using radio buttons in a reactive form, radio buttons in the same group should have the same formControlName. You can also add a name attribute, but it's optional.*"

So, i gave the same formControlName at each radio button and the mention "checked" works now.

Otherwise, to answer my second question, I identified each radio buttons following the "value" property of input, and checked if radio buttons selected :

```
<div *ngIf="formGroupItemSelection.controls.radioBoutton.value==='refNumber'">
```

Hope it can help !

Answer (score 0):

```
initializeForm() {
    this.formGroupItemSelection = this.fb.group({
      refNumber : new FormControl(true),
      partNumber: new FormControl(false),
      itemName: new FormControl(false),
      manufacturerName: '',
      refNumberSelected:[
        null,
        Validators.compose([Validators.required, matchValuesRefNumber(this.listOfItems)])
      ],
      partNumberSelected:[
        null,
        Validators.compose([Validators.required, matchValuesPartNumber(this.listOfItems)])
      ],
      itemNameSelected: [
        null,
        Validators.compose([Validators.required, matchValuesItemName(this.listOfItems)])
      ],
      manufacturerNameSelected:[
        null,
        Validators.compose([Validators.required, matchValuesManufacturerName(this.listOfItems)])
      ]
    })

//This will set the radio button checked no need to add checked attribute you can set cheked dynamically
 this.formGroupItemSelection.get('refNumber ').setValue(true);
this.formGroupItemSelection.get('partNumber').setValue(true);
this.formGroupItemSelection.get('itemName').setValue(true)
  }
```

Comment: "La propriété 'controls' n'existe pas sur le type 'AbstractControl'".

Comment: have you created formControl for your radio button?

Comment: Yes i updated that and it's the same. But normally, i don't need to instantiate FormControl thanks to FormBuilder.

Comment: if you add you can set initial value instead of setting manually

Comment: Ok but I get the same result unfortunately.